# Find integral $\int\frac{\sin\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Please help me to find indefinite integral: $$\int\frac{\sin\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$ Please suggest to me a way to do it.

I tried the substitution $t = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}},\,$ so that $\,dt = -\dfrac{1}{2x^{3/2}}\,dx$.

But I don't know what to do next...

Comment: Try simpler: $t=\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\text{Put }u = \sqrt x \implies du = \frac 1{2\sqrt x}\,dx$$

$$2\int\frac{\sin\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}dx \quad \text{ becomes } \quad2\int  \sin u \,du= -2\cos u + c = -2\cos(\sqrt x) + c$$

Comment: Thx, should have thought of it earlier)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Take $u = \sqrt{x}$ then $du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} dx \implies 2u \ du = dx$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Put $t = \sqrt{x}$. Then, the integrand becomes: $2sin(t)$.